# Magento 2 site fails after upgrading server

Tags: magento2, hosting

We recently finished building a site with a Magento 2 template at [www.cellar2door.com](http://www.cellar2door.com) We were advised to upgrade our blue host hosting to a **VPS** account and did that.

Now the site doesn't show and we get the following text on the home page. Exception: Notice: Use of undefined constant ICONV_IMPL - assumed `'ICONV_IMPL' in /home/cellart1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/StringUtils.php on line 162 in /home/cellart1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: #0 /home/cellart1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/StringUtils.php(162): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Use of undefine...', '/home/cellart1/...', 162, Array) #1 /home/cellart1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Header.php(120): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils->cleanString('Mozilla/5.0 (Ma...') #2 /home/cellart1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Header.php(57): Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header->_getHttpCleanValue('HTTP_USER_AGENT', true) #3 /home/cellart1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderProvider/XssProtection.php(43): Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header->getHttpUserAgent() #4 /home/cellart1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/HeaderManager.php(42): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderProvider\XssProtection->getValue() #5 /home/cellart1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor)) #6 /home/cellart1/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/Response/Http/Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array) #7 /home/cellart1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #8 /home/cellart1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(156): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception)) #9 /home/cellart1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception)) #10 /home/cellart1/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)) #11 {main}`

Bluehost have tried everything they can think off but cannot find a solution.

The developer company is closed now for Chinese New Year so will have to wait until next week to hear back from them.

I was wondering if anyone had had similar problems or could point me in the right direction if it is as simple as editing a line of code?

Comment: you re-index the site @James

Comment: ok i am a bit of a novice how would i do that?

Comment: php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: using composer to do that

Comment: ok I cannot access my admin as the site is down and receiving the error I am getting as per original question. So are you saying I go into my hosting account and into file manager and do this there?

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4002

Comment: Thanks Bhavik, I think this is all a bit beyond me and maybe I will have to just wait for the developers to come back of holidays. I am worried that if I do the wrong thing the site may still not come back and I may end up making the problem worse

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else sees this frustrating message. I also had switched to a VPS on Bluehost and our Magento 2 stopped working with the error the OG posted.

The fix I found was to uninstall Magento from the directory, then reinstall, but on reinstall, the setup wizard informed me that 2 PHP extensions were missing.

I logged into WHM and use Easy Apache to add those extensions, I put the original files back and voila back in business. Its weird that the logs does not mention those extensions.

Here were the missing PHP Extensions:

PHP Extension Intl.
PHP Extension Iconv.

Best regards.